# jar file not up updating values in file

Tags: debugging, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I have a javafx project that I am preparing for distributions. The project works perfectly from the debugger inside NetBeans. I am working on Linux.

But when I run the project from the jar file, there is one function in all the others that does not work. This function is supposed to open the settings file on a button click and alter some values from true to false.

I have changed the settings file's location and tried around google, but all to no avail.

I am still quite a newbie to java, fx, netbeans and java (not so much programming) and making my first experiences.

Any idea why this happens?

```
@FXML
private void openSettingsFile(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    // this test works ....
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("terminal");
    processBuilder.start();

    // this part only replaces the values when I use the debugger ..
    Path path = Paths.get("src/desktop_launcher/Settings.java");
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    content = content.replaceAll(" \"true\"" , " \"false\"");
    Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks like you are trying to manipulate a *source* file and for it to have effect at runtime. How are you compiling the file, building the jar, and reloading the class dynamically at runtime? Apart from anything, you can't expect the `src` directory to be available at runtime. You know that Java is compiled, right??

Comment: I have a series of checkboxes that are supposed to remember their states as being selected (or not) every time I CLOSE and RELOAD the program. When I close the application with the checkbox state changed, it should start the way it was closed. I have created a settings file and the above function is supposed to feed the settings file, which in return feeds the initial state of the checkboxes. I am aware that the location of the settings file is nor ideal. But changing the folder for a try didn't help. Is the file location important for the function to work? It works all right from the debugger

Comment: If it's a settings file, why does it have a `.java` file extension? You should use a text file, probably in a format compatible with [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). As for file location, the `src` folder obviously is not available at runtime, and `Paths.get(...)` is going to resolve relative to the working directory. I would recommend using the users home directory (`System.getProperty("user.home")`) and creating a directory and file inside that.

Comment: it is actually not the settings file, it is a file that creates the properties file .... http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: So you are trying to rewrite a Java source file???

Comment: If the source files are defined as those who are used to run the program, then yes, I am trying to rewrite a source file. Academically speaking, should the above function not be capable of changing the content of any file, independent if it is a source file or not and independent if it is run though a jar file or the debugger?

Comment: Uh, sure, you can change the source file (assuming you have access to it - usually the source code is not even available at runtime), but what effect do you expect that to have?

Comment: Added narrative to answer explaining why your approach (assuming I have understood it correctly) isn't working, though you haven't really said what "doesn't work" means. Do you get exceptions? Does it rewrite the source file but simply not make any difference? What happens? Hopefully the answer will address whatever it is that is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach (which, as far as I understand it, is to try to programmatically change the source file that generates the properties file) will not work at deployment time for a number of reasons.

The first is that the source files are generally not available at runtime: your jar file contains the class files and other resources required to run the application, but typically not the source code (and it's not desirable to include it in the application, in general).

Secondly, you are trying to locate this file from a relative path passed to `Paths.get(..)`. This will resolve relative to the working directory, which is essentially arbitrary (basically "where the application was run from"). So even if the source code were available at runtime, this would not be a reliable way to find it. (My guess is that your debugger runs with the working directory fortuitously set to the parent directory of `src`, but when you run the jar file the most likely location of the working directory is the directory in which the jar file is located. But that is just a guess: it really depends on the configuration of your IDE, debugger, etc etc.)

Thirdly, and probably most importantly, even if the code does find the source file and rewrite it, that's all it will do. Next time you execute the application from the jar file, it won't magically know there is a new version of the source code that has to be compiled and then the resulting class file(s) incorporated into the jar file. So you would have to also include code to compile the new version of your source code (where will you get a compiler? AFAIK not all Java runtimes will include a compiler) and then programmatically insert the new class file(s) into the jar file (how do you even figure out where the jar file is: that is certainly non-trivial and I don't think it can be done in a reliable manner). What if the current user doesn't have permissions to write the directory containing the jar (which is a pretty common scenario..)?

The usual way to load and save startup configuration values is to use the [`java.util.Properties` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). You need an external location to store the properties file, that you can be certain exists on the user's computer: a convenient way to do this is to create an application-specific directory in the user's home directory. The user's home directory can be accessed via `System.getProperty("user.home");` (The system property `user.home` is one of those that is [guaranteed to exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--).).

I would recommend using a separate class to manage the configuration properties. For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesAccessor {

    private static final Path USER_HOME = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

    private Properties props ;
    private Path path ;

    public PropertiesAccessor(String relativePath) {
        path = USER_HOME.resolve(relativePath);

        props = new Properties();

        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            try {
                props.load(Files.newBufferedReader(path));
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                System.err.println("Warning: could not load properties file. Using defaults.");
                exc.printStackTrace(System.err);
                loadDefaults();
            }
        } else {
            loadDefaults();
        }

    }

    public Boolean getBooleanValue(String key) {
        String value = props.getProperty(key);
        return value == null ? null : Boolean.valueOf(value) ;
    }

    public void updateBooleanValue(String key, boolean value) {
        props.setProperty(key, Boolean.toString(value));
    }

    public void writeProperties() throws IOException {
        if (! Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
            Files.createFile(path);
        }
        props.store(Files.newBufferedWriter(path), "Properties updated "+LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    private final void loadDefaults() {
        // in real life, you might keep a default properties file bundled with
        // the application and read that here, e.g. 
        // props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/default-startup.properties"));

        props.setProperty("config.value1", "true");
        props.setProperty("config.value2", "false");
    }
}
```

And now you can use this in your application. Just load the properties in the `init()` method and save them back in the `stop()` method. **Note that executing this will create a directory called `.myApp` in your home directory, and a file called `startup.properties` inside it.**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StartupPropertiesExample extends Application {

    private PropertiesAccessor config ;

    private CheckBox value1 ;
    private CheckBox value2 ;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        config = new PropertiesAccessor(".myApp/startup.properties");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        value1 = new CheckBox("Value 1");
        value2 = new CheckBox("Value 2");
        value1.setSelected(config.getBooleanValue("config.value1"));
        value2.setSelected(config.getBooleanValue("config.value2"));

        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(e -> Platform.exit());

        VBox root = new VBox(10, value1, value2, exit);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        config.updateBooleanValue("config.value1", value1.isSelected());
        config.updateBooleanValue("config.value2", value2.isSelected());
        try {
            config.writeProperties();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("Warning: could not save properties");
            exc.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: James, many thanks for your valuable and technical advice. Your observations really answer a lot of questions I had about java foundations.... (others to come..). I have tried the Get.Path method with other folder locations and it really did not seem to work well. And my main interest  about storing and retrieving properly settings values became clear and the solution is very elegant.  Thanks a lot for the time and patience to look into this matter and answer so broadly.

Comment: James, why is the line "config.updateBooleanValue("config.value1", value1.isSelected());" only working in the stop method?

Comment: @Rainer not sure I understand the question. The code in the stop method updates the properties with the new values from the UI and saves them to the properties file. You don't need to do that until the program exits.